# Angular JS : rest API is called with a delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

Am trying to call some REST APIs from my AngularJS code. When looking at the page load time (say through Developer Tools -> Network in a browser like Firefox), the icons in the page load quickly. Then there is about 100 to 200ms gap, only after which the REST API is even called. I worked a simple example in Plunkr here :
http://plnkr.co/edit/aTk8D9RXdmqBXoCwpVuG?p=preview

```
return $http({
method: 'GET', 
url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting'
});
}
return restAPIs;
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,restFactoryService){

    restFactoryService.getInstanceDetails().success(function (data){
        $scope.datas=data;  
    });
});
```

I have used ng-repeat in my original code. I initially thought that the slowness was due to that. But, as you can see above, even with a simple REST API call, the delay happens. Also, see the screenshot below showing the page loading. You can see that the page loads in 80ms. Then there is a gap until 240ms, only after which the REST API is called. What is happening between 80ms and 240ms time frame? Why can't the REST API be called at 80ms itself?

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem... You ask "why this ajax request take some time" ?

Comment: Did you put a `debugger` before the request to see the time its reached ?

Comment: @enguerranws my question is : after 80ms, we see in the browser that nothing takes place until 240ms. Why this pause?

Comment: @Jean nothing is happening on the network, but the JS engine may be busy on something else (synchronously parsing loaded scripts, waiting for a ready event, etc...)

Comment: I suggest you make at least two calls and ignore the call. There might be some delay due to initialization the required components.

Answer (score 4):

I updated you plunker and added a bunch of `performance.now()`s to get detail info. The first timestamp is placed in html as the first element of `head`.

Here is what I got [all results in ms] -- the exact numbers may be different from run to run:

```
Application ready after: 207.77.
Window loaded after: 281.24 
Http requested started after 13.47 after ready.
Http response came after 161.80 after the request.
$http call took less than 0.88.
```

Here is updated [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/DDiMTIopNM9RRTvMb2lZ?p=preview).

It seems that it takes ~200ms to parse all html and javascript. Btw. angular starts bootstrapping your app on `DOMContentLoaded` ([more about bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)).

Comment: If one need to mitigate the gap anyway, I would suggest use some preloading techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the request is not sent at that exact 80ms because **there is some code inside `$http` method** like reading the config, building the data, creating http request object,....All of this **does take time** which causes delay until the request is actually on the wire.

> What is happening between 80ms and 240ms time frame

That's the time taken by the code inside `$http` method.

To be exact, there is also time taken to bootstrap your angular app, create your `restFactoryService`, make `restFactoryService.getInstanceDetails()` function call,...

Comment: Actually the very call to `$http` takes ~1ms, bootstrapping the app is less then <25ms (giving a gross margin error for angular's compilation).

Comment: @artur grzesiak: The point here is: the request is not sent immediately, there is time taken to initialize the app (some are mentioned in my answer) and make the call. I put ... because I don't want to go into much detail. I just want to `raise awareness` that the request is sent only after initialization, making function calls,..

Answer (score 1):

If you check the plunker on chrome, you will see that there is no so long delay.  On IE 11 there is small gap too (like in your firefox) but i see that the `greetings` webservice is waiting for `angular.min.js.map` file to be retrieved. That may indicate that this browser uses less maximum number of connections for webpage. After that if you rerun code - the gap is not found.